# Orthodoxy & Kenosis in Philippians 2:6-11

Tags: exegesis, christology, eastern-orthodox, philippians, kenotic-theology

What is the Orthodox exegesis of Philippians 2:6-11, in particular, the phrase "He emptied Himself?"

Answer (score 0):

Philippians 2:6-9

> 6 Who, though he was in the form of God,
> did not regard equality with God something to be grasped. 7     Rather, he emptied himself,
> taking the form of a slave,
> coming in human likeness;
> and found human in appearance, 8 he humbled himself,
> becoming obedient to death,
> even death on a cross. 9 Because of this, God greatly exalted him
> and bestowed on him the name.

These verses are the biblical cornerstone of the Orthodox doctrine of kenosis (emptying) according to which Christ condescended from absolute divinity in order to become a man and thus give salvation to humankind. To paraphrase St. Athanasius, "The Word became man, that man might become divine." According to the summary of [Archimandrite Irenei Steenberg](https://www.holycrossoca.org/newslet/1511.html) of the Holy Cross Orthodox Church"

> God becomes man that man might become God. The response to the
> dehumanization of His creature is the anthropization of the Son,
> Himself. God becomes that which is ailing. For God, in His grace, in
> His eternity, cannot be defeated. So by [God] taking up the weak creature
> into His own life, man inherits God’s immortality. That which is the
> Son’s, becomes the creature’s. God becomes man, that man might become
> God.

Kenosis (emptying) refers not to every aspect of divinity but only to those attributes of God that are incompatible with becoming fully human. These attributes include God's omnipotence, omnipresence, and omniscience as well as his eternity, infinity, and immutability, etc. Jesus could not be fully human if he, as a human being, was also all-powerful or present everywhere. He couldn't grow if he was unchangeable. He was not infinite, etc. To quote the [New World Encyclopedia](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Kenosis)

> Christian theology posits a God outside of time
> and space, who enters into time and space to become human (incarnate).
> Since the incarnate Jesus is simultaneously fully human and fully
> divine, Kenosis holds that these changes were temporarily assumed by
> God in his incarnation, and that when Jesus ascended back into heaven
> following the resurrection, he fully reassumed all of his original
> attributes and divinity.

To summarize, Orthodox theology understands the verses mentioned in the OP to teach that Christ, instead of holding on to absolute divinity, came to earth as a human being, an obedient slave to God. He emptied himself of certain divine attributes and willingly assumed the limitations of human flesh, in order to fulfill the divine plane of redemption.

Comment: How does this reconcile with Colossians 1:19 if Kenosis means Jesus let go of some of His divine attributes?